# How to temporarily stop and start Networking by using Netplan?

Tags: networking, network-manager, netplan

I am using VM console to test services on Ubuntu 20.04. Sometimes I need to stop all networking temporarily but I can't find any cmd to stop netplan like `nmcli networking off` or `systemctl stop networkmanager` or `ifdown`. Is there a way to stop and start networking by using `netplan`.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry I mean 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Netplan page](https://netplan.io/):

> Netplan reads network configuration from /etc/netplan/*.yaml which are written by administrators, installers, cloud image instantiations, or other OS deployments. During early boot, Netplan generates backend specific configuration files in /run to **hand off control of devices to a particular networking daemon**.

- Netplan provides the recipe; it doesn't the real work of configuring devices and making connections. Netplan is the wrong place to try to bring your network connections up/down. Netplan is the right place to change your network configuration *while the network is down*.
- The supported networking daemons are **NetworkManager** and **systemd-networkd** (Ubuntu installs NetworkManager). Only one can be in use at a time. Bring your network up/down using the daemon.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean that if I want to use start/stop network adapter I must use one of the **NetworkManager** or **systemd-networkd** instead of netplan?

Comment: That's indeed what the second bullet says.